# How to read fingerprint from connected device in android app using Xamarin forms android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fingerprint

I want to connect the physical biometric device MSF100 (mantra fingerprint) with my android app which was developed in Xamarin forms c#. Please help me to read and validate the fingerprint using that device in xamarin android c#.

Comment: I would look for an SDK/Lib/NuGet package published by the manufacturer of that external biometric device. Then follow their documentation on how to integrate it into the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Your post does not contain any meaningful details we could use to help you.